# Can I pick a dropbox file through FileDialogue and store the path in my database?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database hosted on SharePoint.

I have a continues form called frmAttachments. It has one PK field, one text field (txtAttachmentPath) and one combo (cboFileType). Text field txtAttachmentPath has a property "Is Hyperlink" set to "Yes".

I made a command button that open FileDialogue, picks the file and pass the path to the txtAttachmentPath field as its value. When I click the txtAttachmentPath field, it opens the file. All beautiful so far...

However, I can only pick files on my local machine (the same would apply to any other user). Is possible that I can pick and store the path of a dropbox file using the same technique: click on command button, get navigated to the organisation's DropBox folder, select a file and get that path stored in my txtAttachmentPath field, so that it can be seen and opened by any database user?

The code below (for my command button cbtAttachment) works like a charm, but I can only pick and store files from my local machine, meaning that other dbs users cannot access it.

```
Private Sub cbtAttachment_Click()
   
Dim f    As Object
Dim strFullFilePath As String ' Full file path

Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)

f.allowMultiSelect = False
 
f.Show
 
strFullFilePath = f.SelectedItems(1)

Me.txtAttachemtPath = strFullFilePath
 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If Windows Explorer can navigate to location then FileDialog should be able to.

Comment: Thanks @June7 - I am using Chrome, but nevertheless, FileDialogue doesn't let me navigate to the DropBox. That might be my problem, my DropBox settings...

Comment: You use Chrome to navigate folders? I did not say Internet Explorer, I said Windows Explorer.

Comment: :-) Lack of coffee! I meant, I cannot see DropBox in my WE - I can see OneDrive though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with hyperlinking to specific directories in Dropbox.

Install Dropbox desktop, if the application is not installed already. [Dropbox Application Install Link](https://www.dropbox.com/install)

You will want to save the attachment paths so you do not run into issues with differing user profiles

SetPathToDropbox = Environ$("%UserProfile%") & "\Dropbox - \path\to\document\or\file"

A similar post for OneDrive was what help me through this [Right Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68217019/how-to-build-a-variable-filepath-as-link-or-path-in-ms-access-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a solution for navigating to a file on our organisation's DropBox (FileDialogue cannot see it for some reason), but I did make it work through OneDrive where colleagues can save paths to shared reports, photos, etc. within the DBS, and then open those files on their individual laptops, desktops, etc.